# Color Invariants usage with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, invariants

I'm trying to find the color invariants of a photo. I searched it and found that I need to find the value of `c1` as its simplest feature. We can find `c1` by this formula `c1=(r/max(g,b))`.

When I try to find img cols and rows with `img.shape` and split this image b,g,r.

```
import cv2
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('CU.png')

b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

cv2.imshow('Image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(img.shape)
rows,cols,channels = img.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        b = img[i,j,0]
        g = img[i,j,1]
        r = img[i,j,2]
        x = (r/max(g,b))
        c1= math.atan(x)
        plt.plot(i,j,c1)

plt.show()
```

I thought I should split the picture into rows and columns and then break it down into b, g, r. I had to find c1 using the values b, g, r in each row and column, but I'll do this `c1` later.

I wonder if anyone knows about it? How to find color constants or what should I do or is my method of finding this `c1` correct?

Comment: Can you upload your example image?

Comment: it can be any image. i just want to learn how can i do this work

Answer (score 0):

[Due to Th. Gevers, J. van de Weijer, H. Stokman, Color Feature Detection article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgUKG.png), the color invariants are detecting with these formulas. And the [C1,c2,c3 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvYnr.png) can be detected like in the attached image. But if we implement the solution like your formula, we can use:

```
import PIL
import math

def invariant_r(img):
  c1 = np.zeros(32,32)
  for i in range(0, 32):
    for j in range(0, 32):
      r, g, b = img.getpixel((i, j))
      x = (r/max(g,b))
      c1[i][j]= math.atan(x)
  return c1

def invariant_g(img):
  c1 = np.zeros(32,32)
  for i in range(0, 32):
    for j in range(0, 32):
      r, g, b = img.getpixel((i, j))
      x = (g/max(r,b))
      c1[i][j]= math.atan(x)
  return c1

def invariant_b(img):
  c1 = np.zeros(32,32)
  for i in range(0, 32):
    for j in range(0, 32):
      r, g, b = img.getpixel((i, j))
      b = (b/max(r,g))
      c1[i][j]= math.atan(x)
  return c1
```